# Maintain column structure after merging csv files

Tags: r, twitter, csv, merge

I am merging almost 3.000 csv files, removing the duplicate rows, and writing a new csv datafile. For this purpose I used the following code:

```
#Grab our list of filenames
filenames <- list.files(path = ".", pattern='^.*\\.csv$')
#Read.csv function
my.read.csv <- function(fnam) { read.csv(fnam, header=FALSE, skip=1, sep=';', col.names=c('ID','tweet','author','local.time','extra'), colClasses=rep('character', 5))}
#Read all the files into one data.frame
my.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, my.read.csv)) length(my.df[,1])
#Remove the duplicate tweets
my.new.df <- my.df[!duplicated(paste(my.df$tweet, my.df$author)),]
length(my.new.df[,1])
#Write new dataframe as a .csv file
write.csv(my.new.df, file =paste("Dataset", ".csv"))
```

Although the function does what it suppose to do, the output file is messy. The original csv files all have the following structure:

```
tweet                                                         author    local.time
2012-06-05 00:01:45 @A (A1):  Cruijff z'n (...)#bureausport.  A (A1)    05-06-12 00:01
2012-06-05 00:01:41 @B (B1):  Welterusten #BureauSport        B (B1)    05-06-12 00:01
2012-06-05 00:01:38 @C (C1):  Echt (...) #bureausport         C (C1)    05-06-12 00:01
2012-06-05 00:01:38 @D (D1):  LOL. #bureausport               D (D1)    05-06-12 00:01
```

However the output file has the following structure:

```
,"ID","tweet","author","local.time","extra"
1,"2012-06-05 00:01:45 @A (A1):  Cruijff z'n (...)#bureausport.","@A (A1)","05-06-12 00:01"
2,"2012-06-05 00:01:41 @B (B1):  Welterusten #BureauSport","@B (B1)","05-06-12 00:01"
3,"2012-06-05 00:01:38 @C (C1):  Echt (...) #bureausport","Aliceislovely (Alice Luyben)","05-06-12 00:01"
4,"2012-06-05 00:01:38 @D (D1):  LOL. #bureausport","@D (D1)","05-06-12 00:01"
```

It thus presents the data as a string rather than in columns. I hope you can help me adjust the code (above) such that the output file has the same column structure as the original (input) csv files.

btw the following code was used to create the csv files:

```
library(XML)   # htmlTreeParse

twitter.search <- "Keyword"

QUERY <- URLencode(twitter.search)

# Set time loop (in seconds)
d_time = 300
number_of_times = 3000

for(i in 1:number_of_times){

tweets <- NULL
tweet.count <- 0
page <- 1
read.more <- TRUE

while (read.more)
{
# construct Twitter search URL
URL <- paste('http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=',QUERY,'&rpp=100&page=', page, sep='')
# fetch remote URL and parse
XML <- htmlTreeParse(URL, useInternal=TRUE, error = function(...){})

# Extract list of "entry" nodes
entry     <- getNodeSet(XML, "//entry")

read.more <- (length(entry) > 0)
if (read.more)
{
for (i in 1:length(entry))
{
subdoc     <- xmlDoc(entry[[i]])   # put entry in separate object to manipulate

published  <- unlist(xpathApply(subdoc, "//published", xmlValue))

published  <- gsub("Z"," ", gsub("T"," ",published) )

# Convert from GMT to central time
time.gmt   <- as.POSIXct(published,"GMT")
local.time <- format(time.gmt, tz="Europe/Amsterdam")

title  <- unlist(xpathApply(subdoc, "//title", xmlValue))

author <- unlist(xpathApply(subdoc, "//author/name",  xmlValue))

tweet  <-  paste(local.time, " @", author, ":  ", title, sep="")

entry.frame <- data.frame(tweet, author, local.time, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
tweet.count <- tweet.count + 1
rownames(entry.frame) <- tweet.count
tweets <- rbind(tweets, entry.frame)
}
page <- page + 1
read.more <- (page <= 15)   # Seems to be 15 page limit
}
}

names(tweets)

# top 15 tweeters
#sort(table(tweets$author),decreasing=TRUE)[1:15]

write.table(tweets, file=paste("Twitts - ", format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %H_%M_%S %Y"), ".csv"), sep = ";")

Sys.sleep(d_time)

} # end if
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want your output to have tab-separated fields, and no quotes around the values in each column. Here's how you can do that:

```
write.table(mtcars, "mtcars.txt", quote=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

To quickly preview and compare the output of calls to `write.csv()` and the above code, try something like this with your own data:

```
write.csv(head(mtcars))
write.table(head(mtcars), quote=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

---

**Edit:** If (instead of tab-separated fields) you need the data in each column to be completely aligned horizontally, have a look at `write.fwf` in package `gdata`, [as demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844462/setting-column-width-in-a-data-set). (The "fwf" stands for "fixed width format".)

Comment: As you mentioned your approach creates tab-seperated fields. Although this does look nice in the .txt format, for analyzing purposes I would like the output files to be .csv. And thus simply changed .txt into .csv however the tab separation does not work in the .csv format. Do you know how I can use write.csv in such a way that the data is pasted in the right columns (maintaining the column structure of the original .csv files)?